# jupyterlab with pylsp .virtual_documents error

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, language-server-protocol

I'm using `jupyterlab` 4.1.5 and am trying to follow these instructions: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/lsp.html

I `pip` installed `pylsp` using the provided command. When I start `jupyterlab` it says the lsp extension was initialized. However, as soon as I open a .ipynb, I get this error:

```py
[W 2024-03-21 16:54:39.012 ServerApp] [lsp] initialization of shadow filesystem failed three times
check if the path set by `LanguageServerManager.virtual_documents_dir` or `JP_LSP_VIRTUAL_DIR` is correct;
if this is happening with a server for which you control (or wish to override) jupyter-lsp specification
you can try switching `requires_documents_on_disk` off. The errors were:
[PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'), PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'),
PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')]
```

I think I want to follow the suggest of turning off `requires_documents_on_disk`. It's unclear to me how I'm supposed to do that. I tried adding it as a language server setting/property (per those same instructions) and I set it to `false`. That didn't fix it.

Comment: If you are in individual user, toggling `requires_documents_on_disk` is not something you would do - this is to be changed in server specification. We could try toggling it for pylsp in a future version. I would suggest to follow the instructions in the error message and set either the environment variable `JP_LSP_VIRTUAL_DIR`  or pass `--LanguageServerManager.virtual_documents_dir='/path/to/some/folder/with/write/access'` on jupyterlab startup?

Comment: Thank you, @krassowski, setting that env var solved my permissions issues. I mistakenly thought "server" was referring to my instance of Jupyterlab running on the server, not the language server. I still haven't been able to get the lsp working, but that probably belongs in a separate question.